# UV maps don't work on metaballs that where converted to meshes?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

So I was working on a monster model in Blender and then I got to UV unwrapping it. Just to find out it apperently was not working. There might be a couple reasons why this is not working for me.

1. I rigged the model before adding textures
2. It was originally made with metaballs. Which I later converted to a mesh.
3. I need to do an extra step.

I dont want to start all over again and I think it would be useful to know how to UV unwrap mesh converted metaballs.

[image]